# It is possible to embed a 3D view in a application both for Android & iOS?

Tags: android, ios, react-native, 3d, flutter

I'm getting my hands wet with a project that absolutely need an interactive 3D model in a view of the application (which should be both Android or iOS).

I've tried to figure out what can I do with React Native, which expose two libraries that I can't install for a lot of issues with Android SDK or other modules that I've encoutered.

React Native module #1: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-3d-model-view
React Native module #2: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-gl-model-view

So I moved on Flutter which is a lot more flexible on setup and I've found an interesting package (this one: https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/flutter_3d_obj#-readme-tab-) but, with this one too, I've found a lot of problems installing the current version of Flutter, etc.

So, I would like to ask: what is the convenient way to display a 3D model which is possible to build both for Android and iOS?

Answer (score 0):

Since react-native uses javascript, you can easely build an app with [Expo](https://expo.io/) and [Three.js](https://github.com/expo/expo-three).

By using those 2 tools, you shouldn't have any problem with the android sdk, and will be able to build for both iOS and android with ease.

I have no idea about the Flutter part.